# Htaccess 301 redirect with conditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On


# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/searchPage.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This works great when I type `category/business`, but I also want the url to be written if someone type the old url such as `searchPage.php?crs_category=business` to be redirected as `category/business` with a 301 code letting the SEO knows that this is the new address.

Note:
The reason why there is the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/searchPage.php
```

condition is because I am using the Slim framework and where I want all request to be redirected to index with the exception of the searchPage for routing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this right under the commented out `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /searchPage\.php\?crs_category=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks. would it also be possible to replace the %20 space character code with an acutal space for instance if searchPage.php?crs_category=html and css is click it will turnout category/html%20and%20css